# kurento can't receive rtp from gstreamer correctly

Tags: gstreamer, kurento

I installed kurento media server, and run the kurento java tutorial,(RTP receiver), kurento offer a gstreamer pipeline,

```
    PEER_V=23490 PEER_IP=10.0.176.127 SELF_V=5004 SELF_VSSRC=112233 
    bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -t \
    rtpbin name=r \
    v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency \
! rtph264pay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=(int)103,clock-rate=(int)90000,ssrc=(uint)$SELF_VSSRC" \
! r.send_rtp_sink_1 \
r.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink host=$PEER_IP port=$PEER_V bind-port=$SELF_V \
'
```

this is the pipe which I simplified from officail pipeline, and it could run successfully;
but there is a problem when I implement this pipeline with c or c++ code.
kurento can't receive rtp stream, but I can receive rtp stream with my own rtp receiver that I wrote by c++.
the kurento media server log warnings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJImf.png)
it looks like that kurento doesn't process video stream, but audio stream.
but I never send audio stream.
So I want to know how to change c code to fit the kurento, let my video stream to kurento. my code [enter link description here](https://github.com/lrtxpra/gstreamer-app-development/blob/master/monitor_client.cc)

Answer (score 0):

yes , After a few days of toss， I figure out this problem today,

```
PEER_V=23490 PEER_IP=10.0.176.127 SELF_V=5004 SELF_VSSRC=112233 
bash -c 'gst-launch-1.0 -t \
rtpbin name=r \
v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency \
! rtph264pay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=(int)103,clock-rate=(int)90000,ssrc= 
(uint)$SELF_VSSRC" \
! r.send_rtp_sink_1 \
r.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink host=$PEER_IP port=$PEER_V bind-port=$SELF_V \
```

this pipeline, if you change payload to 96,then kurento media server will report the same warning as the picture in question.
so I think that it's my payload setting error.
then I add a pad probe to detect pad's caps.
s.h.i.t, it's true,
but I don't know why I set caps but not effective,
so I set the property "pt" of rtph264pay, and it runs successfully.
the code is [enter link description here](https://github.com/lrtxpra/gstreamer-app-development/blob/master/kurento-rtp-push-stream/push_stream_to_kurento_java_rtp_receiver.cc)